How to define string representation of my class object in PowerShell?
I'm trying to make some PowerShell cmdlets in C# and created a DataChunk class for storing binary data. It just holding byte[] array. The goal was to read bytes from file into DataChunk to show it how I need it. So I wrote ToString() method. But it seems that PowerShell not using it. Why?
PS> $data = Read-BinaryData test.bin
PS> $data.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    DataChunk                                System.Object

This is what I need:
PS> $data.ToString()
07 65 20 AE F6 8D 4F 00 97 A8 33 C9 81 EB 80 AE 92 87 7D 08

This is how it works now:
PS> $data

Count
-----
   20

The class is simple:
public class DataChunk
{
    byte[] data;
    public int Count => data.Length;
    public override string ToString() { ... }
}

How to make my own class to show up in PowerShell like I need to?

You can define your own format data for your type, see about Format.ps1xml. In this case, you can use a CustomControl with the ExpressionBinding tag.
First you need to define the ps1xml and store it in a file, for this example, the file is saved in the current location with name DataChunk.format.ps1xml:
Set-Content DataChunk.Format.ps1xml -Value @'
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>MyCustomTestView</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>DataChunk</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <CustomControl>
        <CustomEntries>
          <CustomEntry>
            <CustomItem>
              <ExpressionBinding>
                <ScriptBlock>
                  $_.ToString()
                </ScriptBlock>
              </ExpressionBinding>
            </CustomItem>
          </CustomEntry>
        </CustomEntries>
      </CustomControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
'@

Then you need to update the format data for your custom type using this file:
Update-FormatData -PrependPath .\DataChunk.format.ps1xml

And lastly you can test it:
Add-Type @'
using System;

public class DataChunk
{
    private readonly byte[] _data;
    public int Count => _data.Length;
    public DataChunk(byte[] bytes) => _data = bytes;
    public override string ToString() => BitConverter.ToString(_data).Replace('-',' ');
}
'@

$bytes = 7, 101, 32, 174, 246, 141
[DataChunk]::new($bytes)

# Should output:
#
# 07 65 20 AE F6 8D

Worth noting here, if you are developing a binary module, instead of manually updating the format data, you would add the path to the format.ps1xml file to your module manifest (.psd1) in the FormatsToProcess element.


Santiago's helpful answer provides the best solution to your problem.

To address your question:

But it seems that PowerShell is not using it [.ToString()]. Why?

Because your DataChunk .NET type has at least one public property, it is handled by PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system.

Only .NET primitive types (in short, most number types, as well as pointer types and  [bool] and [char]) and types without (public) properties render via the return value of their .ToString() methods.

Any instance of a non-primitive type with at least one public property whose type doesn't have formatting data associated with it (an example of such formatting data is in Santiago's answer), results in the object rendering by its properties, which is what you experienced.

With up to 4 public properties, implicit Format-Table formatting is applied (tabular format, with each property in its own column, as in your case), whereas 5 or more result in implicit Format-List formatting (each property on its own line).

An ad hoc workaround that forces use of your type's .ToString() method - aside from calling that method explicitly - is to use PowerShell's string interpolation, i.e. an expandable string ("..."):
 # Short alternative to: 
 #    $data.ToString()
 #    $data | ForEach-Object ToString
 "$data"


I knew that formatting with ps1xml will help, but I didn't understand why ToString() is not working. Now I do.
Thanks a lot!
